# Run OpenVPN client on VPS

Tags: vpn, iptables, openvpn, vps

I tried to run OpenVPN as a client on my VPS, but since the traffic is routed I can no longer connect to the VPS via SSH. I tried the following approach but it didn't work

```
ip rule add table 128 from 50.1.2.3
ip route add table 128 to 50.1.2.0/24 dev tun0
ip route add table 128 default via 10.10.10.5
```

I got the default gateway from

```
root@server:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.10.1      10.10.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.10.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.10.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

Which part am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the default gateway gets changed by OpenVPN, and that breaks your current SSH connection unless you set up appropriate routes before you start OpenVPN.

For a solution that uses iptables and ip (iproute2), it is assumed that the default gateway interface before OpenVPN is started is "eth0". The idea is to ensure that when a connection to eth0 is made, even if eth0 is not the default gateway interface anymore, response packets for the connection go back on eth0 again.

Using below distinct numbers for clarity, although the same number could
be used for all:

```
# set "connection" mark of connection from eth0 when first packet of connection arrives
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234

# set "firewall" mark for response packets in connection with our connection mark
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 4321

# our routing table with eth0 as gateway interface
sudo ip route add default dev eth0 table 3412

# route packets with our firewall mark using our routing table
sudo ip rule add fwmark 4321 table 3412
```

Some Linux versions need to add "via" to the routing table entry:

```
# our routing table with eth0 as gateway interface
sudo ip route add default dev eth0 via 12.345.67.89 table 3412
```

where "12.345.67.89" is the original non-VPN gateway.

Comment: Second solution worked smoothly on debian 10. First solution without "via" just locked me out completely