# Dual VPN network

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, iptables

I have to connect a server with a VPN service (anonymizer) and route all internet traffic through said VPN service.

I've been struggling for over 2 weeks to get these commands with the help of this [Run OpenVPN client on VPS](https://superuser.com/questions/1203940/run-openvpn-client-on-vps):

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234

sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 4321

sudo ip route add default dev enp3s0 via 192.168.0.1 table 3412

sudo ip rule add fwmark 4321 table 3412
```

These commands work perfectly. The server connects to the VPN service, gets the tun0 interface and I'm able to SSH to my server both locally and remotely.

Now I'd like to add my own OpenVPN server (to my server) with the tun1 interface and SSH to my server through the second VPN.

Ok, I've got OpenVPN working with the tun1 interface showing up, but here hell rises.

I was convinced that this command should solve the problem:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i tun1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

but it doesn't...

As soon as the first VPN connects, the system routing table changes and I cannot connect remotely to my server with a VPN client to the second VPN.

If I disconnect the server from the first VPN, then I can connect to the server with the second VPN.

I know there should be a command out there that saves my day.

Any help appreciated

Edit:

I have tried this solution but it doesn't work either:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1234
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i tun1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2345

sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1234 -j MARK --set-mark 4321
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 2345 -j MARK --set-mark 5432

sudo ip route add default dev enp3s0 via 192.168.0.1 table 3412
sudo ip route add default dev tun1 via 10.8.0.1 table 3412

sudo ip rule add fwmark 4321 table 3412
sudo ip rule add fwmark 5432 table 3412
```

Edit:

This is the routing table:

```
root@test:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.9.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
10.9.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun1
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
128.0.0.0       10.9.8.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
225.12.10.15    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123865/discussion-on-question-by-iola-dual-vpn-network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest an alternate approach without involvement of iptables at all:

```
ip r add default dev enp3s0 via 192.168.0.1 table 101
ip rule add iif lo from 192.168.0.0/24 not to 192.168.0.0/24 table 101
```

Or

```
ip r add 192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 table 101
ip r add default via 192.168.0.1 table 101
ip rule add iif lo from 192.168.0.0/24 table 101
```

In case `not` does not work in the way I assume it to.

Comment: The first snippet routes all internet traffic to the default gateway ignoring Nordvpn.

Comment: The second is interesting. It works beautifully. I can SSH remotely and locally but I still cannot connect remotely to the second VPN

Comment: I think you should read about the `multihome` option in openvpn and try it perhaps (and `local` that the manual suggests, if it doesn't work). Have you checked whether only `proto udp` causes you the problem?

Comment: If I change both server and client to `proto tcp` it doesn't make any difference. I will deepen the openvpn documentation. Thank you

Comment: Hmm `proto` takes either `tcp-server` or `tcp-client` but not `tcp` AFAIK

Comment: You are a TOTAL genius. I have added `multihome` to the `server.conf` of the second VPN and IT WORKS !!! I can SSH and connect to openvpn from everywhere. I was convinced I would never solve this. I cannot express all my gratitude!